# Client certificate doesn't work on 1 windows 7 machine but works fine from others

Tags: windows, ssl

The clients are windows 7 sp1 64 bit on all the machines.
The install of the certificate went fine except for one machine.
It just says the web page cannot be displayed in ie(with friendly errors turned off) and in chrome and FF it shows connection interrupted.
The Advanced options for SSL (as in the TLS and SSL versions) are exactly the same in the different browsers on different machines.
I even blown the profile away on the machine and recreated her, with the same effect.
There is is no roaming profiles. Just folder redirection of desktops and documents folder.

Would anyone have any suggestions on where to go from here?

Answer (score 0):

This is not really an answer, but it might grow into one if you provide more details. Here are some steps you need to do to narrow the problem:

- Check if you can reach other hosts from the bad machine, i.e. find out if the problem is related to the overall connectivity of this machine or is only for the connection between the one machine and the specific server.
- In case parts of the server can be reached with plain HTTP check if you can reach this parts from the bad machine.
- Check if there is some middlebox (load balancer, firewall) in between which might affect the connection. Client certificates do not work if you have SSL interception in between.
- Make a packet capture from a good and a bad connection to the same server and compare them. If you add them to the question use cloudshark or similar so can can look at them at more detail, instead of posting a hex dump or screen shot here.